# Rails. ActiveRecord::Migration. Reversible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I read RoR guide and I don't understand the next line:

> If you wish for a migration to do something that Active Record doesn't know how to reverse, you can use reversible

What does it mean "doesn't know how to reverse"? How to distinguish what Active Record can reverse and what cannot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply, there are two kinds of operations in AR migrations:

1) Rails automatically knows how to rollback (revert) those operations in migrations, for example:

```
def change
   add_column :users, :age, :integer
end
```

migration means add column **age**, rollback means remove column **age**. Or **create_table**, reverse operation is **drop_table**. This operations you can put into **change** method in migration and rails knows what to do when rollback / reverse those migrations.

2) Rails needs to help how to process **migration** and **rollback** process, usually it is operations which somehow modifies data.

```
def self.up
   add_column :users, :name, :string
   add_column :users, :surname, :string
   say_with_time 'Split username into name and surname' do
       Users.select(:username).all.each do |user|
          user.name = user.username.split(/ /)[0]
          user.surname = user.username.split(/ /)[1]
          user.save!
       end
   end
   remove_column :users, :username
end
```

As you can see, this operation is quite complicated. Rails does not know how to reverse this operation, so you have to write reverse operation code in **self.down**:

```
def self.down
   add_column :users, :username, :string
   say_with_time 'Join name and surname into username' do 
       User.all.each do |user|
         user.update_attributes(username: "#{user.name} #{user.surname}")
       end
   end

   remove_column :users, :name
   remove_column :users, :surname
end
```

and thats all...